# How PHP mail function works behind the scene?

Tags: php, email

I have done quite some Googling, but couldn't find answers to my specific questions.

I understand the syntax of `mail()` and the step to edit php.ini files. But why would  the SMTP server accept connection request when I don't provide authentication information?

For example, if I want to send email through my gmail account, I would have to log in using my email address and password. But it appears that using PHP `mail()` enables me to completely bypass this step.

How does the `mail()` function work behind the scene?

Comment: that's because `mail()` works off your own server and doesn't need to verify you, while when you connect to an outside source, it is required since you're using "their" mail server. Call this an answer in its own right, if not "the" answer.

Comment: if what I wrote above doesn't satisfy you, you'll need to say so. Otherwise, read the manual on mail and related RFC's or I can pop an answer in below quoting those. Your question doesn't have anything to do with programming, but core server authentication procedures.

Comment: @Fred. thanks. Although it doesn't really make it clearer. I will try to find the relevant RFC's. Manual on mail doesn't help.

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll pop something below. I know what to look for.

Comment: Ok John; I've popped something for you below, in addition to what I mentioned in comments, being more of a "in a nutshell" answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info.

Comment: You're welcome John.

Answer (score 1):

As per the manual on PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function and related RFC's

and listed under:

> *"Note:
>   The following RFCs may be useful: » RFC 1896, » RFC 2045, » RFC 2046, » RFC 2047, » RFC 2048, » RFC 2049, and » RFC 2822."*

From RFC 2049 http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2049.html

```
   [RFC-1421]
        Linn, J., "Privacy Enhancement for Internet Electronic
        Mail:  Part I -- Message Encryption and Authentication
        Procedures", RFC 1421, IAB IRTF PSRG, IETF PEM WG,
        February 1993.
```

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1421.html

Privacy Enhancement for Internet Electronic Mail:
Part I: Message Encryption and Authentication Procedures

```
        1.  This RFC's measures are restricted to implementation at
            endpoints and are amenable to integration with existing
            Internet mail protocols at the user agent (UA) level or
            above, rather than necessitating modifications to existing
            mail protocols or integration into the message transport
            system (e.g., SMTP servers).

        2.  The set of supported measures enhances rather than restricts
            user capabilities.  Trusted implementations, incorporating
            integrity features protecting software from subversion by
            local users, cannot be assumed in general.  No mechanisms
            are assumed to prevent users from sending, at their
            discretion, messages to which no PEM processing has been
            applied. In the absence of such features, it appears more
            feasible to provide facilities which enhance user services
            (e.g., by protecting and authenticating inter-user traffic)
            than to enforce restrictions (e.g., inter-user access
            control) on user actions.

        3.  The set of supported measures focuses on a set of functional
            capabilities selected to provide significant and tangible
            benefits to a broad user community.  By concentrating on the
            most critical set of services, we aim to maximize the added
            privacy value that can be provided with a modest level of
            implementation effort.
```